# How could an expression of enumeration type fall outside that enum's range?

Tags: c++, enums

The C++ standard on [enums](https://eel.is/c++draft/enum#dcl.enum-8) says

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a hypothetical integer type with minimal width M such that all enumerators can be represented. The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

A footnote then clarifies that

> This set of values is used to define promotion and conversion semantics for the enumeration type. **It does not preclude an expression of enumeration type from having a value that falls outside this range.**

I understand these promotion and conversion semantics to be referring to what happens when you convert to and from enums as defined in [7.6.1.9.10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#10)

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a complete enumeration type ... If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values, and otherwise, the behavior is undefined ...

When the footnote says that it does not preclude an expression of enumeration type from having a value outside of the enum's range, is it **only** referring to the possibility of undefined behavior, or is there some other way of having an expression of enum type that falls outside of the enum's range? It would seem odd to me for the standard to describe a scenario that's only possible through undefined behavior, because undefined behavior is unpredictable by definition.

My main goal is to learn how to better read and understand the C++ standard, so I'm not looking for practical advice on using c++ enums, but I welcome any tips on better understanding or citing the standard.

Comment: `enum_type foo = static_cast<enum_type>(invalid_value);`

Comment: `enum Foo { alpha, beta };` has a bit-width of 1, so it's range is 0 .. 1 (inclusive).  `Foo foo{static_cast<Foo>(2)};` falls outside Foo's range.

Comment: Both of these examples would fall into the category of undefined behavior, right? So if these are the only way of getting an expression of enum type outside of its range, then it does sound like that footnote only refers to undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, the phrase "behavior is undefined" in the citation means undefined behavior.

Comment: @Cjp: The standard is talking about what happens when you do those things. It is defining the behavior of these operations. "*Both of these examples would fall into the category of undefined behavior, right?*" Where does the standard say that this is true?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's how I understood [7.6.1.9](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#10). "If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values, and otherwise, the behavior is undefined". That would apply to the examples given by NathanOliver and Eljay.

Comment: The question must be what "enumeration doesn't have underlying type" means -IMHO.

Comment: `enum Foo { alpha = 1, beta = 4 };` needs enough bits to store 4. And if it has that, it can also store 5, perhaps the result of `alpha | beta`, even though that is outside the range of enums given.

Comment: @Red.Wave, all enumerations have an underlying type, but some enums don't have a _fixed_ underlying type (i.e. they are unscoped enums without a specified enum-base). So `enum class Foo {alpha, beta};` and `enum Foo : int {alpha, beta};` both have a fixed underlying type. `enum Foo {alpha, beta};` does not have a fixed underlying type.

Comment: @BoP, this could be pointing to where my misunderstanding is, but I see these as two different concepts: there's the _range_ of the enum, and then there's all of its enumerators (i.e. named values in the enum). Your comment points out a valid expression of type Foo that is not named by any of Foo's enumerators, but it does fall within the range of Foo as defined by [9.7.1.8](https://eel.is/c++draft/enum#dcl.enum-8).

Comment: @Cjp That's a typo I guess. Because AFIAK `enum` has a default `unsigned int` underlying type, unless explicitly specified. So the paragraph should've meant that if the underlying type is not specified, casting from values not in range of `[min,max]<enum>` is UB, and the underlying type is unspecified. But almost every compiler has a default underlying type.